# How to create a dataframe with dynamic column length in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am creating  dataframes in R like below.

```
len5<-data.frame("C1"=character(0),"C2"=character(0),"C3"=character(0),"C4"=character(0),"C5"=character(0), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

len6<-data.frame("C1"=character(0),"C2"=character(0),"C3"=character(0),"C4"=character(0),"C5"=character(0),"C6"=character(0),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

len7<-data.frame("C1"=character(0),"C2"=character(0),"C3"=character(0),"C4"=character(0),"C5"=character(0),"C6"=character(0),"C7"=character(0),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

etc

However I need to create it dynamically in a loop starting from length 5 to 15
for dataframe of column length starting from 5 to 15.

Is there any way of doing that? all the dataframes will be characters only

Thanks
Tanmay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `lapply` to create a `list` of `data.frames`.  It is better to keep that in the `list` and not create multiple objects in the global environment.

```
i1 <- 5:15
lst <- lapply(i1, function(x)  data.frame(setNames(replicate(x,character(0)), 
                           paste0("C", seq_len(x))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
names(lst) <- paste0("len", i1)
```

In case, the program needs to take objects from global environment

```
list2env(lst, .GlobalEnv)
str(len5)
#'data.frame':   0 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ C1: chr 
# $ C2: chr 
# $ C3: chr 
# $ C4: chr 
# $ C5: chr
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick help. It solved my problem. However just one quick qs. Is there a way to create separate list for each item like lst1 , lst2 ...lst 15?

Comment: Hi Akruri I am unable to insert data inside individual element like lst$len7 , lst$len10 using for loop. How to assign data to this list item from within loop?

Comment: @Tanmay The `lst1` to `lst15` is not clear to me.   Here, we have a single list with 11 data.frame objects.  Regarding your second question, can you elaborate a bit more as I don't know how you are doing this

Comment: Hi Akruri I have an array rept4 of some length . I have to split the array according to size and create a matrix and then assign to the dataframe. Now if i use  arr4len<-length(rept4)
 windowsize<-x
 numrows<-ceiling(arr4len/windowsize)
 k<-0
 for (i in 1:numrows){
  for(j in 1:windowsize){
    k<-k+1
    lst$len15[i,j]<-rept4[k]
  }
 }  that is working for me as lst$len15[i,j] is accessible. But inside an outer for loop when I calling the sub routine i dont know how to call lst$lenx[i,j] where x is valiable from "for ( i in 5 to 15) for ( x in 5:15 )

Comment: @Tanmay Could you please post as a new question with the code as it is not clear to me

Comment: for ( x in 5: 15){

 arr4len<-length(rept4)
 windowsize<-x
 numrows<-ceiling(arr4len/windowsize)
 k<-0
 for (i in 1:numrows){
  for(j in 1:windowsize){
    k<-k+1
    lst$lenx[i,j]<-rept4[k]
  }
 }
}

Comment: @Tanmay what is `rept4`  Can u post as a new question?

Comment: rept4<-"CGCCCCCTGCTGGCGACTAGGGCAACTGCAGGGTCCTCTTGCTCAAGGTGAGTGGCAGACGCCCACCTGCTGGCAGCCGGGGACACTGCAGGGCCCTCTTGCTTACTGTATAGTGGTGGCA"
rept4<-unlist(strsplit(rept4,""))

Comment: @Tanmay Looks like this would go as a new question

Comment: Created a new one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48019909/inserting-data-inside-dataframe-within-a-list-dynamically

Comment: @Tanmay Looks like docendo is working on your problem.

Comment: Hi Akrun... My problem is resolve. Thanks for your help.. Only one thing.. I am unable to understand the mechanism of your 2 nd code line lst <- lapply(i1, function(x)  data.frame(setNames(replicate(x,character(0)), 
                           paste0("C", seq_len(x))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)) ...... can you please suggesnt me reading to understand the working?

Comment: @Tanmay What it is doing that we loop through element 5:15 with `lapply` into a `list`, then in each of the `list `elements, replicate the `character(0)` by that value, set the names of that with sequence of the value pasted with the 'C', You can check `seq_len(5)`  and convert it to data.frame so that the 'C1' to 'C5' becomes the column names of the dataset