# inserting data inside dataframe within a list dynamically

Tags: r

I have a problem as below.

```
rept4<-"CGCCCCCTGCTGGCGACTAGGGCAACTGCAGGGTCCTCTTGCTCAAGGTGAGTGGCAGACGCCCACCTGCTGGCAGCCGGGGACACTGCAGGGCCCTCTTGCTTACTGTATAGTGGTGGCA"
rept4<-unlist(strsplit(rept4,""))
```

Now as per suggestion I have a list of dataframes as below.

```
i1 <- 5:15
lst <- lapply(i1, function(x)  data.frame(setNames(replicate(x,character(0)), 
                           paste0("C", seq_len(x))), stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
names(lst) <- paste0("len", i1)
```

My question is how to put data inside every dataframe from within a loop depending upon the length.

```
  for ( x in 5: 15){

 arr4len<-length(rept4)
 windowsize<-x
 numrows<-ceiling(arr4len/windowsize)
 k<-0
 for (i in 1:numrows){
  for(j in 1:windowsize){
    k<-k+1
    lst$lenx[i,j]<-rept4[k]
  }
 }
}
```

Here I am trying to access `lst$lenx` and x-th element like `lst$len10` or `lst$len11` etc.

Comment: This looks like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: can you please suggest how to access list of dataframe within a for loop? I meant to say i can access lst$len10[i,j] ... thats ok but how to replace len10 with lenx so that i can get to elements at the x th datafrom in the list lst?

Comment: I got my answer.. thanks guys

Comment: What should be your end result?

Answer (score 0):

If the task is to split `rept4` into a list of data.frames, I would do splitting and creating the data.frames in two steps: (1) split the string in substrings of lengths `i1`, (2) turn the substrings into data.frames

```
rept4<-"CGCCCCCTGCTGGCGACTAGGGCAACTGCAGGGTCCTCTTGCTCAAGGTGAGTGGCAGACGCCCACCTGCTGGCAGCCGGGGACACTGCAGGGCCCTCTTGCTTACTGTATAGTGGTGGCA"
i1 <- 5:15
end <- cumsum(i1)
start <- end - i1 + 1L
lst <- lapply(stringr::str_sub(rept4, start, end), 
              function(x) 
                setNames(
                  as.data.frame(t(unlist(strsplit(x, ""))), 
                                stringsAsFactors = FALSE),
                paste0("C", seq_len(nchar(x))))
)
names(lst) <- paste0("len", i1)
lst
```

> ```
> $len5
>   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5
> 1  C  G  C  C  C
>
> $len6
>   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6
> 1  C  C  T  G  C  T
>
> $len7
>   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7
> 1  G  G  C  G  A  C  T
>
> $len8
>   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8
> 1  A  G  G  G  C  A  A  C
>
> $len9
>   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9
> 1  T  G  C  A  G  G  G  T  C
>
> $len10
>   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 C10
> 1  C  T  C  T  T  G  C  T  C   A
>
> $len11
>   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 C10 C11
> 1  A  G  G  T  G  A  G  T  G   G   C
>
> $len12
>   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 C10 C11 C12
> 1  A  G  A  C  G  C  C  C  A   C   C   T
>
> $len13
>   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 C10 C11 C12 C13
> 1  G  C  T  G  G  C  A  G  C   C   G   G   G
>
> $len14
>   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 C10 C11 C12 C13 C14
> 1  G  A  C  A  C  T  G  C  A   G   G   G   C   C
>
> $len15
>   C1 C2 C3 C4 C5 C6 C7 C8 C9 C10 C11 C12 C13 C14 C15
> 1  C  T  C  T  T  G  C  T  T   A   C   T   G   T   A
> ```

Answer (score -1):

One solution to your problem is to parse a string to a variable name as indicated in this blog post:https://www.r-bloggers.com/converting-a-string-to-a-variable-name-on-the-fly-and-vice-versa-in-r/

With your code I did this simplified example:

```
for (x in 5: 15){
  print(eval(parse(text = paste("lst$len",x,sep=''))))
}
```

In short, you can use: `eval(parse(text = paste("lst$len",x,sep='')))`